# How to define database variable for logging in Kettle?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

I would like to know if there is a proper way to pass the database connections variable so they can be used in the logging sections of both jobs and transformations.

Regards,

Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the kettle.properties from the top menu.

If you want to do it for *ALL* the log use the variables like KETTLE_JOB_LOG_* and KETTLE_JOB_TRANS_*. There is no way to do it for job and transformation at the same time, but it is defining 8 variables (instead of 4) which can be copy/pasted.

If you want to do it for specific job and/or transformation, define your own variables like log_bd, log_table,... and use them as ${log_db}, ${log_table},... You have to define the parameters for each job and transformation. Or else, you could write a small program to change the xml of the .ktr and .kjb.